# Drastic performance differences: debug vs release

Tags: c++, performance, visual-studio-2012

I have a simple algorithm which converts a bayer image channel (BGGR,RGGB,GBRG,GRBG) to rgb (demosaicing but without neighbors). In my implementation I have pre-set offset vectors which help me to translate the bayer channel index to its corresponding rgb channel indices.
Only problem is I'm getting awful performance in debug mode with MSVC11. Under release, for an input of 3264X2540 size the function completes in ~60ms. For the same input in debug, the function completes in ~20,000ms. That's more than X300 difference and since some developers are runnig my application in debug, it's unacceptable.

My code:

```
void ConvertBayerToRgbImageDemosaic(int* BayerChannel, int* RgbChannel, int Width, int 

Height, ColorSpace ColorSpace)
{
    int rgbOffsets[4]; //translates color location in Bayer block to it's location in RGB block. So R->0, G->1, B->2
    std::vector<int> bayerToRgbOffsets[4]; //the offsets from every color in the Bayer block to (bayer) indices it will be copied to (R,B are copied to all indices, Gr to R and Gb to B).
    //calculate offsets according to color space
    switch (ColorSpace)
    {
    case ColorSpace::BGGR:
            /*
             B G
             G R
            */ 
        rgbOffsets[0] = 2; //B->0
        rgbOffsets[1] = 1; //G->1
        rgbOffsets[2] = 1; //G->1
        rgbOffsets[3] = 0; //R->0
        //B is copied to every pixel in it's block
        bayerToRgbOffsets[0].push_back(0);
        bayerToRgbOffsets[0].push_back(1);
        bayerToRgbOffsets[0].push_back(Width);
        bayerToRgbOffsets[0].push_back(Width + 1);
        //Gb is copied to it's neighbouring B
        bayerToRgbOffsets[1].push_back(-1);
        bayerToRgbOffsets[1].push_back(0);
        //GR is copied to it's neighbouring R
        bayerToRgbOffsets[2].push_back(0);
        bayerToRgbOffsets[2].push_back(1);
        //R is copied to every pixel in it's block
        bayerToRgbOffsets[3].push_back(-Width - 1);
        bayerToRgbOffsets[3].push_back(-Width);
        bayerToRgbOffsets[3].push_back(-1);
        bayerToRgbOffsets[3].push_back(0);
        break;
    ... other color spaces
    }

    for (auto row = 0; row < Height; row++)
    {
        for (auto col = 0, bayerIndex = row * Width; col < Width; col++, bayerIndex++)
        {
            auto colorIndex = (row%2)*2 + (col%2); //0...3, For example in BGGR: 0->B, 1->Gb, 2->Gr, 3->R
            //iteration over bayerToRgbOffsets is O(1) since it is either sized 2 or 4.
            std::for_each(bayerToRgbOffsets[colorIndex].begin(), bayerToRgbOffsets[colorIndex].end(), 
                [&](int colorOffset)
                {
                    auto rgbIndex = (bayerIndex + colorOffset) * 3 + rgbOffsets[offset];
                    RgbChannel[rgbIndex] = BayerChannel[bayerIndex];
                });
        }
    }
}
```

What I've tried:
I tried turing on optimization (/O2) for the debug build with no significant differences.
I tried replacing the inner `for_each` statement with a plain old `for` loop but to no avail. I have a very similar algorithm which converts bayer to "green" rgb (without copying the data to neighboring pixels in the block) in which I'm not using the `std::vector` and there there is the expected runtime difference between debug and release (X2-X3). So, could the `std::vector` be the problem? If so, how do I overcome it?

Comment: I don't get it. What's the problem? It's perfectly normal, expected and acceptable, that DEBUG mode will be significantly slower than the release mode. That's why you have two different modes. Debug mode contains a lot (really a lot) information (meta data) for debugging purposes.

Comment: @KirilKirov Debug is useful, but often times too slow to be usable. That's the problem. So you want to enable it selectively, only on the components of interest. That's the solution.

Comment: @KirilKirov: I expect performance differences between debug and release, but I've never encountered X300 performance differences. My algorithms is a simple single iteration over the input. I'd expected a reasonable difference in times

Comment: I see. I didn't know you can selectively disable/enable debug "features". Thanks, noted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you use `std::vector`, It will help to disable iterator debugging.

[MSDN shows how to do it.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985939.aspx)

In simple terms, make this `#define` before you include any STL headers:

```
#define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 0
```

In my experience, this gives a *major* boost in performance of Debug builds, although of course you do lose some Debugging functionality.

Comment: +1. I believe this is the main cause of difference, good answer.

Comment: @MatsPetersson That's the "beauty" of C++ and STL in particular. A single line in your program may be hiding quite a lot of stuff. At times that stuff is very costly.

Comment: Nice, I was sure that'd be it but it didn't help... any other ideas?

Comment: I take it back. Defining it in the preprocessor did the trick

Comment: Do you know whether a vector built with and without that flag has the same ABI ? If this changes the ABI, then one may have to define it on the command-line, for example.

Comment: As far as *I* am aware the ABI is unaffected - perhaps we have more detailed knowledge elsewhere in SO or maybe ask it as a question.

Comment: In addition to this, also read about the `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP` environment variable for MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

In VS you can use below settings for debugging, Disabled (/Od). Choose one of the other options (Minimum Size(/O1), Maximum Speed(/O2), Full Optimization(/Ox), or Custom). Along with  iterator optimization which Roger Rowland mentioned...

Comment: As I've mentioned in my post, I tried using /O2 but with no significant differences