# Save the debugging state to skip long computations

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2012, save

I have a c++ program which starts with a "heavy" computation done by a library.
It takes about 10 second in release mode, but more or less 15 minutes in debug mode. So, without any hack, if I want to debug the rest of the program I have to waste the initial time.

A possible solution is to save to file the results of the computation in the release mode and read them in the debug mode with preprocessor directives like that:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    read_result_from_file();
#else
    do_heavy_computation();
    save_result_to_file();
#endif
```

But I was wondering if other solutions exist. For example is it possible to save the state of the debug session so that from the second time on I can start debugging after the initial computation?

Comment: Breakpoint after the computation? Or if in debug-mode do a mock computation?

Comment: Run the program in a VM. When the computation completes, take a snapshot. To debug again, restore the snapshot.

Comment: I guess he has that breakpoint, but it won't save him time if the computation lasts that long.

Comment: Proabably [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15949582/drastic-performance-differences-debug-vs-release/15950409#15950409) will be helpful. You can also try debugging release build most of the time and switch to debug when it is not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite likely that your long runtime is (at least in part) due to extra debug code in the iterators and related functions in the STL. Have a look at the MS page for [iterator debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh697468.aspx).

That may not take your 15 minutes to 10 seconds, but it may take it down to something closer to 10 seconds than 15 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Many IDEs have the possibility to assign different debug options to different (sub)projects/libraries or even to different translation units. If you use make and/or command line compiler, you have similar options there. So depending on the IDE, you could put the heavy setup calculation into its own library and always compile that library (or the TU) in release mode, unless you want to debug the calculation itself of course.

That way, you can debug the other parts of the program but have the fully optimized calclulation.